# Makefile - when running shell commands the output doesn't have line breaks

Tags: bash, makefile, sh

I'm editing a makefile that ran a lot of sh scripts, and i just added one that runs a terraform command.
When i use directly the .SH file (or the command manually in console, the output is OK, but if i ran it inside the makefile, the output is all together, without spacing or line breaks.

Is there any way to fix this?

PFB commands and outputs.

**runcommands.sh** (it ran as ./runcommands.sh init/plan/etc)

```
terraform $1
```

output:

> Terraform initialized in an empty directory!
>
> The directory has no Terraform configuration files. You may begin
> working with Terraform immediately by creating Terraform configuration
> files.

**Makefile:**

```
plan:
    $(shell ./runcommands.sh init)
```

output:

> Terraform initialized in an empty directory!  The directory has no
> Terraform configuration files. You may begin working with Terraform
> immediately by creating Terraform configuration files.

Comment: Surely you get an error when `make` tries to execute `Terraform initilized...` as a command.  Remove the `$( shell` cruft and just execute the command.  You are not trying to build a string.

Comment: https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recipe:

```
plan:
    $(shell ./runcommands.sh init)
```

does not do what you seem to think it does. The `$(shell ...)` syntax executes the command and builds a string.  Because of its location in the Makefile, that string is then executed as a command.  You almost certainly do not want the output of `./runcommands.sh` to be executed.  You want:

```
plan:
    ./runcommands.sh init
```